# How to arrange position absolute div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i want arrange my divs as fit column style dynamically with jQuery same like the image attached. I have a parent div and inside there can be a lot of boxes which are position absolute. These boxes have same width but height will vary according data in it them. My HTML is

```css
.container{
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.box{
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 24%;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
.col-1,.col-6{
  height: 300px;
}
.col-2,.col-8{
  height: 400px;
}
.col-3,.col-5{
  height: 200px;
}
.col-4,.col-7{
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box col-1">Block 1</div>
   <div class="box col-2">Block 2</div>
   <div class="box col-3">Block 3</div>
   <div class="box col-4">Block 4</div>
   <div class="box col-5">Block 5</div>
   <div class="box col-6">Block 6</div>
   <div class="box col-7">Block 7</div>
   <div class="box col-8">Block 8</div>
 </div>
```

Divs arrangements:

[image]

Comment: How do we know how many boxes should be in a column?

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. It's a css issue and not a jquery one. Either make your boxes position relative, width sth like 44%, margin 2% or if you want to keep the position absolute set the overflow-y to auto and have a fixed height.

Comment: [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) as well would be helpful to take a look at.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using Flexbox.  Simply make the css of your container

```
<code>
.container{max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 800px;
}
</code>
```

See a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/adamturner93/qo72dsuj/

Comment: Excellent. Setting the height is essential though.